# How does a delegate receive its arguments?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, lambda

Here's a sample using the List collection class:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();

List<int> evenNumbers = list.FindAll(delegate (int i)
{
return (i % 2) == 0;
});
```

I've often wondered how the delegate passed to FindAll() is itself called back once for each item in the list.

This also leads to another question, from a piece of code I'm working with currently. It's using a lambda expression instead of a straight delegate:

```
    class SampleViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private int quantitySaved;
        public int QuantitySaved
        {
            get { return quantitySaved; }
            set
            {
                if (quantitySaved != value)
                {
                    quantitySaved = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged(p => QuantitySaved);
                }
            }
        }

      //class continues below....
    }
```

The ViewModelBase class looks like this (cut for brevity):

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<ViewModelBase, T>> property)
    {
        MvvmHelper.NotifyPropertyChanged(property, PropertyChanged);
    }
}
```

The 'p' in the SampleViewModel lambda resolves to a ViewModelBase when the QuantitySaved property is set, but how does that resolution actually work at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

These are definitely 2 separate questions.

### Delegate parameters

Delegate types always specify all parameters and return types.
The `FindAll` method [has the following signature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z.aspx):
`public List<T> FindAll(Predicate<T> match)`.
`Predicate<T>` is a delegate [with the following signature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz.aspx):
`public delegate bool Predicate<in T>(T obj)`.

When `FindAll` invokes the predicate, it must supply the `T obj`, like this: `match(item)`, which will return a `bool`.

### Lambda Expressions

Lambda Expressions are a really cool feature of .NET 4.  They are **very different** from Lambda Functions, even though the syntax is *identical*!

Basically, when you write a Lambda Function, it is compiled just like any other code.  However, when you write a Lambda Expression, the compiler actually generates a bunch of **metadata** that fully describes the code.  Usually, the code never actually executes.

This is very useful in scenarios like the `PropertyChanged` event, because this event needs to know the name of the property, not just the value.  The Lambda Expression can be analyzed, and it will indicate that the property being changed is `"QuantitySaved"`.

Using Lambda Expressions allows you to write code that is strongly-typed, but allows that code to be analyzed instead of executed.  It's a great feature of the language and enables many great features like LINQ to SQL, but is definitely tricky to understand!

Comment: Note also that type resolution for Lambda expressions is done at *compile time*, not run time.

Comment: Yeah, that is part of what makes it much better than reflection!

Comment: @BrunoSantos "This type parameter is contravariant. That is, you can use either the type you specified or any type that is less derived. For more information about covariance and contravariance, see [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx)"